# Nlog Configuration with ServiceStack using NLog.Web.AspNetCore properties (${aspnet-user-identity} , ${aspnet-request-url}, etc.)

Tags: logging, servicestack, nlog

I am trying to get ServiceStack's Nlog configuration to work with NLog.Web.AspNetCore properties but when properties such as ${aspnet-user-identity} are used inside the nlog.config file, they always returned empty. Any ideas on how to configure this?

Comment: You need to hookup NLog with the Microsoft `IServiceProvider` so it can acquire `HttpContextAccessor`. Not sure how ServiceStack works together with Microsoft Extension Logging and Microsoft Dependency Injection. See also `SetupNLogServiceLocator` : https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/443069282603c4ad3723d1859c2bd0216facab79/src/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/AspNetExtensions.cs#L69

Comment: Maybe you also need to explicitly register `HttpContextAccessor` if not using `UseNLog()`. See also https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#hostcontexttrygetcurrentrequest